# Using VS Code with Bookdown

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, r-markdown, bookdown

I have installed the R extension for VS Code. I am creating a book with **bookdown**, which is an extension of **RMarkdown**.

There is a `Knit` option (`Ctrl + Shift + K`). By default, it runs

> `rmarkdown::render("path/to/current/file", encoding = 'UTF-8')`.

[@CarlosLuisRivera pointed out that I had `render_site` here, rather than `render` before.]

In order to make **bookdown** work, I just need it to run

> `rmarkdown::render_site()` or `bookdown::render_book()`.

The `encoding` is the default, so that isn't needed. **bookdown**. Importantly, though, there *shouldn't* be a filename. I can't for the life of me work out how to adjust the settings to stop it from putting the filename in.

There is a setting `r.rmarkdown.knit.command`. This doesn't seem to do anything when the active file is called `index.Rmd`. Otherwise, whatever I write there gets appended with `(path/to/current/file, encoding = 'UTF-8')`.

Even if I could get this fixed, I wanted to use VS Code for its preview—the RStudio in-built one is poor. When I try to preview, it can't compile anything, throwing an error:

> The path C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Maths/Teaching/ST333/LectureNotes/libs/jquery-3.6.0 does not appear to be a descendant of C:/Users/USERNAME/vscode-R/tmp/.

The log also includes

> output file: C:/Users/USERNAME/.vscode-R/tmp/index.knit.md

so I guess it's trying to make it in the wrong place.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the default knit option, which is specified at first in `r.rmarkdown.knit.command`, is `rmarkdown::render_site("path/to/current/file", encoding = 'UTF-8')`. The default is `rmarkdown::render`. Probably, you can render your Rmd files, after (i) you set `rmarkdown::render` to `r.rmarkdown.knit.command` and (ii) add `knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {rmarkdown::render_site(inputFile, encoding = encoding, output_format = "all") })` or `knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {bookdown::render_book(inputFile, encoding = encoding, output_format = "all") })` to the YAML of files.

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera Thanks for catching that mistake and for the suggestion. When I `knit` from a file `01-intro.Rmd`—specifically, not `index.Rmd`—the terminal output ends with `Output created: _book/intro.html`. This is a bit strange. I would've thought it should do `_book/index.html`, as Rstudio does when you hit "Build Book". I just changed `...(inputFile, ...)` to `...(input = ".", ...)` to fix that. I do have to add it to *all* my files. None of apart from `index.Rmd` had YAML before. Hopefully that won't cause any issues/conflicts...

Comment: I still have the issue that the preview is looking in `C:/Users/USERNAME/vscode-R/tmp/`, rather than the directory in which that file I'm viewing lives